# How to perform “Document Access Removal Behavior”

Tags: couchbase-sync-gateway

I went through [this](https://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/2.8/csharp/replication.html#document-access-removal-behavior) document, but unable to remove document access on the sync gateway.

FYI: I'm using Couchbase Lite 2.8.6 on the mobile (Xamarin SDK)

**Document**

```
{
  "channels": [
    "3a7c15ba2241"
  ],
  "docType": "logentry",
  "creator": "14bd9d1d7a",
  "createdOn": "2022-03-30T13:37:42.5070600-04:00",
  "subjectId": "14bd9d1d7a",
  "modifier": "14bd9d1d7a",
  "modifiedOn": "2022-03-30T13:37:42.5070600-04:00",
  "deleter": null,
  "writers": [
    "14bd9d1d7a",
    "7c15ba2241"
  ],
  "sequenceId": "0",
  "_id": "evt..14bd9d1d7a..69856d73a",
  "_rev": null,
  "_deleted": false,
  "insert_id": "evt..14bd9d1d7a..69856d73a",
  "device_id": "5E634E1C226",
  "user_id": "14bd9d1d7a",
  "event_type": "Signup",
  "origin": null,
  "time": 1648661795504
}
```

**Sync function**

```
if (doc.docType === "logentry") {
    channel("logevents");
    return;
}
```

I expected that by doing this in sync gateway, the channel is updated and the user doesn't have the access to `logentry` channel so the document will be purged. But I still see the documents in the device (phone) CB Lite. Based on the documentation, an event is triggered and those documents are purged, which isn't happening.

Can anyone suggest how I can remove document access and subsequently purges the document from the database?